# Single word for a person who always follows their own principles

Tags: word-request

I need a positive word to describe a person who usually sets a lot of rules for himself and also for others and always adheres to his rigid principles. For example, a man who is always punctual, keeps promises, avoids what he thinks they are hamful to his health, so on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What is wrong with *principled*?

> **principled** (*adj*) `of a person or their behavior` acting in accordance with morality and showing recognition of right and wrong

Answer (score 2):

A *stickler* is a person who insists on behaving a certain way (usually adherent to a fixed principle or set of principles).

Definition: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/stickler

> noun
>
> A person who insists on a certain quality or type of behaviour.
>
> ‘he's a stickler for accuracy’
>
> ‘I'm a stickler when it comes to timekeeping’

So you can say (for example): "He's a stickler for punctuality." and so on.

Comment: I think sticklers often impose their expectations on others, not just themselves.

Answer (score 1):

I'd call such a man *disciplined* (or *self-disciplined* if I wanted to point out that they're setting the rules for themselves). *Scrupulous* is also a good word to point out their strict adherence to rules.

Answer (score 0):

"Rigid principles" might convey some negative connotations about the person to which "perfectionist" might be a suitable description, but we are asked for a positive word. I suggest "conscientious": SOED: "habitually governed by a sense of duty; scrupulous."

Comment: Yeeeesss, but what else is relevant or worth knowing about it in this context? When might it be useful and when not? Why? Please edit to *explain* things more helpfully.